# File input on iOS Safari mobile doesn't work when calling click event

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, safari

I have a problem with calling click event on input type file.

The input HTML element looks so:`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture/>`

I'm using it to open camera on mobile device (iphone, ipad). Genrally when I call the click event `input.click()` it works but it stops working when the call is made in an async function e.g.

```js
async function uploadData() {

  await upload();

  input.click()
}
```

When I remove await it is working. The problem occurs only on iphone Safari browser. On android Chrome it works. Have someone any idea why it is not working and how make ot work.

Thank you.